# Grid-lines on a GridView

Tags: android, gridview

How do I define grid-lines for a GridView?
Is there an attribute or do I have to draw my own background with them in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such attribute. The easiest thing is to **create a subclass of GridView and override** `dispatchDraw()` or `onDraw()` to do it yourself.

Comment: How would I then draw the lines?

Comment: @theblitz take a look at the how the lines are drawn in ListView, might be a good place to start..

Comment: @theblitz here is the link http://goo.gl/pBq1R Also if you use chrome you can install this extension that adds a link to the sourcecode from every class page in the api docs https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin

Answer (score 1):

set the background to the view(inflate layout) inside the GridView so that gridview display the line automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a padding for each cell of the grid view so that that looks like the grid line. Each cell say would be made up of a linear layout.

Another way of doing this would be to have the cell as a linearlayout and have a view inside that with width of say 0.5dp and height as mp and vice-versa for the horizontal line.