# In android how to bring gridlines in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, gridlines

After searching out a lot i could able to find the solution of my problem that in Android how

can i make gridlines visible in my gridview....as it seems simple but i still couldn't resolve

the problem do suggest some useful suggestion to make gridlines or borders visible on

gridview.....

[Grid-lines on a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010311/grid-lines-on-a-gridview)

followed the answer suggested for this question but don't know how to create subclass of gridview and override its methods,,..?? 
suggest solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a simpler solution, you could add the border to be drawn in your custom views drawn for each grid item.

Example code:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ExampleAdapter(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewgGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(converView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_example);      
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            //Set holder ids here
            holder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        }
        //Populate your holder here with data here.
        holder.title.setText("My Awesome Title!");
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        return convertView;
    } 
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_item_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
    android:background="@color/grid_border"
    android:padding="1dip" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/title" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks 4 the answer..Will u please elaborate i need horizontal lines after each row in gridview....